# Cannot install Ubuntu invalid parameter

Tags: system-installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9bdn.jpg)so I've been facing this issue for 2 days, when I went to install Ubuntu 20.04, it says invalid paremeter, and I can't go install Ubuntu, my laptop supports 64bits, invalid parameter, how should I fix it guys, please? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Please be specific with details as they do matter. You mention 32-bit; so this is an *arm64* computer (where 64 & 32 bit systems existed; as no *i386* or 32bit ISO existed in 20.04 for x86).  There are also 5 installers used by Ubuntu, selected by ISO being used, but you gave no clues except 20; so is this a Ubuntu Core 20 System?  (not 20.04?).  Details matter if we're to understand & provide meaningful help.

Comment: It'll help if you're fully specific, thank you for your edits. From picture it looks like *amd64* and you've now said 20.04, but not if Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server (thus `subiquity` is the installer), or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (which uses `ubiquity`, which I know can be made to create boot problems if the ISO is written to media incorrectly), or other installer if using 20.04 *flavor*.  *The version of 20.04, eg. 20.04, 20.04.1, ... 20.04.6 may also be helpful; as if using Secure-uEFI 20.04-20.04.5 would not be expected to boot due revoked keys! which is why 20.04.6 was created*

Comment: I tried to use another laptop to install and it worked just fine, but why it says invalid parameter on my main laptop?